# SignalR fired dependency_OnChange lot of times, it must be fired only one time when DB changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, signalr, signalr-hub

For every request, below code is running in our Dashboard page. Due to this, dependency.OnChange fired more times when database value is updated. 
We need dependency.OnChange fired only one time in our application, that is in initial page load only.

```
public List<DashboardFreezedColumns> GetDashboardFreezedColumns(int userId, string checkedEmpIds)
    {
        var columns = new List<DashboardFreezedColumns>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        columns.Add(item: new DashboardFreezedColumns
                        {
                            EmployeeId = (int)reader["EmployeeId"],
                            Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                            Status = (int)reader["Status"],
                            Duration = (string)reader["Duration"]
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return columns;
    }


 private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MessagesHub msg = new MessagesHub();
            msg.SendMessages();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So create the `SqlDependency` only on initial page load. What problem are you having with that?

Comment: How can i create like this... We can create SqlDependency with command but command is present in above method. Whenever refresh the page, the above method will called which contains SqlDependency...

Comment: Oh, refreshing the page. Which is supposed to be pretty much like closing the current browser window / tab, opening a new one, and going to the same page you were on previously. That *should* generally be treated the same as an initial page load. In the explicit close / re-open, you'd want the previous `SqlDependency` to be stopped not when the new window / tab is opened, but when the first window / tab is closed. Which requires a different approach.